# Have file data (garbage code) - need to download actual file

Tags: php, download

We are receiving file data from a third party API call that returns the content type in one variable and the file contents in another. The file contents are "garbage code." For example:

```
$doc->fileContents = "A�[�j쎪A����Kb����m��= ....";
$doc->fileType = "application/msword";
```

I need to be able to provide my users a clickable method for downloading the file, but simply writing the contents to a file and forcing a download with that content type simply opens a file containing all that garbage... not the real file contents.

EDIT: Per Patrick Q's request, I did it the standard fwrite way:

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w'); // filename is generated elsewhere
fwrite($fp, $doc->fileContents);
fclose($fp);
```

So the question is, how do I create a real, usable file out of this garbage?

Comment: That "garbage" looks like binary data. It probably *is* the actual file data.

Comment: "simply writing the contents to a file and forcing a download with that content type".  Can you show the code where you tried that?

Comment: Patrick, see amended post. Used fwrite to add contents to the newly-opened file, then forced the download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data looks like binary file data. There's no need to write it to a file first, just make sure you set the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header to `binary` when you send it to the browser for downloading.

I'm assuming you already have a way of mapping `$doc->fileType` to a filename with the proper extension, I'll just hardwire `.doc` here since your example is an `application/msword` document.

```
// your logic here to determine the filename sent to the browser
$filename = "file.doc";

// set the minimum appropriate HTTP headers
header('Content-Type: ' . $doc->fileType);
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($doc->fileContents));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); // this is an important one

// send the file and stop
echo $doc->fileContents;
exit;
```

If you *are* writing it to file first, make sure you open it in **binary** mode:

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $doc->fileContents);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks very much, Rick!